# python script to keep duplicate rows based on condition on columns in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write a python script that keeps the duplicate rows only, based on conditions on columns. For instance, my `input` csv file looks like:

```
Name, Apt_Number, Block_Number, .... , Other_Columns
John, apt1,       ABC, .............., dummyVal
Marie, apt2,       ABC, .............., dummyVal
John, apt3,       XYZ, .............., dummyVal
Sam, apt4,       ABC, .............., dummyVal
Sam, apt5,       LMO, .............., dummyVal
```

I want my `output` csv file to look like this:

```
    Name, Apt_Number, Block_Number, .... , Other_Columns
    John, apt1,       ABC, .............., dummyVal
    John, apt3,       XYZ, .............., dummyVal
    Sam, apt4,       ABC, .............., dummyVal
    Sam, apt5,       LMO, .............., dummyVal
```

i.e. I want to keep rows where same `name` apprear more then once and `block_Number` is different. Can some one suggest me how can i implement this using python? Which data structure I can explore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think my answer is very elegant, but you could use a for loop with the data after reading it from the csv file. Use pop() to remove a row from the dataset, so you only scan over it once.

```
import csv
data = []
with open('input.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

duplicate_names = []
while data:
    row = data.pop()
    dup_exists = False
    for other_row in data:
        if row['name'] == other_row['name']:
            duplicate_names.append(other_row)
            data.remove(other_row)
            dup_exists = True
    if dup_exists:
        duplicate_names.append(row)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = []
    for key in duplicate_names[0]:
        fieldnames.append(key)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in duplicate_names:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Someone else out there might know some better Python mastery and have a shorter way of doing this.